# Android - create alarm with adb commands

Tags: android, adb

I would like to create an alarm with adb commands, e.g. the phone should wake up in 50 seconds. I have tried shell script with sleep command but when the phone goes in sleep mode the device does not wake up in time.

Is there a way to do this?

My test procedure is as following:

- enable a wake up in 50 seconds (still researching the commands)
- turn off the screen (adb shell input keyevent 26)
- wait 50 seconds (sleep 50)
- turn on the screen and unlock the device (adb shell input keyevent 3 & adb shell swipe x1 y1 x2 y2)

Once the device is in sleep mode the **sleep 50** take longer than expected. Therefore I need to know if I can enable a wake up using the alarm manager.

Comment: what you meant by wake and sleep ? display on and off ?

Comment: @Rilwan: I have updated the question with the test procedure.

Comment: "enable a wake up in 50 seconds" -> are you referring  to 'turn on screen'  by wake up ?

Comment: @Rilwan: wake up is not equal turn on screen. The "turn on screen" will only work if the device is out of sleep. Some kind of alarm needs to be set up previously but I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: turn on screen wont wake up host processor from hibernation ? or which module wake up are you referring to ?

Answer (score 1):

You might have to install busybox and use `adb shell busybox`[`rtcwake`](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman8/rtcwake.8.html)

Comment: thanks, but this will not work for longer sleep cycles, e.g. sleep 500. You need to set an alarm that will make sure to take the device out of sleep. Have you tried your approach and measured the sleep time?

Comment: I think even after turn off screen, host and attached modules will be awake until idle time. so measure sleep time can only be verified by checking sleep specific logs or measuring current consumed by your device.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but your solution is not helping. Is there anything similar to pmset in Android? That might solve this issue.

Comment: `rtcwake` , Have you tried this ? 
http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman8/rtcwake.8.html

Comment: Thanks, I think this will do it but how can I set a wake up in Android using ADB commands?

Comment: isn't it working inside adbshell ? `adb shell rtcwake`, I haven't tried though.

Comment: the command does not exist: $ adb shell rtcwake
/system/bin/sh: rtcwake: not found

Comment: if you are aware of `busybox`, you can use most unix commands in android.Download from here - http://www.busybox.net/downloads/binaries/. And push to your device. `adb shell busybox rtcwake` should work!

Comment: @Rilwan , rtcwake is good answer, I think you better add is as a solution. thx